# PowerShell - GoFigure Math

Tags: .net, powershell, math

I'm trying to recreate and working on a Small Project similar to GoFigure ( Windows WEP 16 bit Math game ), using BODMAS / PEMDAS / GEM Rules

PS Code will Randomly pick numbers from 1 to 9
To these random numbers, random Operators ( /, *, +, - ) are applied and we get a Target Number

This Target number will be presented in the game with the #4 Numbers and the #4 operators are shown
User will select any of the #4 numbers and #3 Operators to get the Projected Targets

I'm using ArrayList (not PS Array), to build the Targets and the Numbers used to achieve it

1st Target is at Index[0], Next Target at Index[8] ....
Numbers and Operators used for that Target are at Index[1...7]

Basically Arraylist looks like below

```
36  34  34  18  8   10  34  36  10
7   7   7   7   7   7   5   5   5
*   *   +   +   -   -   *   *   *
5   5   5   5   5   5   7   7   3
+   -   *   -   *   +   -   -   -
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2   7
-   +   -   *   +   *   +   +   +
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   2   

------------------------------------------  
    7       5       3       2
------------------------------------------
```

Here is my dilemma ....

The ArrayList has repeated Targets (34 repeated thrice and 36 twice),
the Number order as well Operator order is different ( 2nd figure )

So technically these Targets are not duplicates
FirstIndex(), LastIndex() might not be helpful, as there are #3 repeating items or might be more

When I display a Target to the user, say 34, user can achieve it in #3 ways

Say I showcase Target at Index[8] = 34, calculation is ((7*5)-3)+2  ##  34
so i will be looking at index[9..15] as the correct solution

What if user calculates as

```
((7+5)*3)-2 ##  34 
or
((5*7)-3)+2 ##  34
```

how can I check this or handle this ?

```
((7*5)+3)-2 ##  36
((7*5)-3)+2 ##  34
((7+5)*3)-2 ##  34
((7+5)-3)*2 ##  18
((7-5)*3)+2 ##   8
((7-5)+3)*2 ##  10
((5*7)-3)+2 ##  34
((5*7)-2)+3 ##  36
((5*3)-7)+2 ##  10
((5*3)-2)+7 ##  20
((5*2)-7)+3 ##   6
                                            
------------------------------------------  
    Targets Count : 30
                                            
    7       5       3       2
------------------------------------------
```